# How to display expandable ListView which include parent and child dynamically updated?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to display expandable listview which contains parent and childs and even sub childs.
These data will be accessed from the server. Data can be returned as JSON data.

I want to access parent and childs which is associated with that parent. Childs may have sub childs also.

```
 Ex:
  Name       Parent        Level       categoryId
  Audio       0               1           101
  Video       0               1           102
  songs      101              2           201
  data       101              2           202
  myhost     201              3           301
  HD         102              2           401
  TV         401              3           500
```

Above example shows the data which is available now.

My code is attached

```
try {
    res1= httpclient1.execute(httppost1);
    responseBodys1 =EntityUtils.toString(res1.getEntity());

    JSONObject jsObject = new JSONObject(responseBodys1);
    JSONArray demo= jsObject.getJSONArray("categories");

    System.out.println("demo=="+demo.length());
    ArrayList<String> map = new ArrayList<String>();
    childs.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
    ArrayList<Integer> map1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> map3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<demo.length();i++)

    {
        JSONObject movie = demo.getJSONObject(i);
           ctName = movie.getString("ctName");
           ctParent= movie.getInt("ctParent");
           int ctLevel = movie.getInt("ctLevel");
           ctCategoryId=movie.getInt("ctCategoryId");
           map.add(ctName);
          map1.add(ctParent);
          // map1.add(ctLevel);
           map3.add(ctCategoryId);

          System.out.println("Map1-===>"+map);
           System.out.println("Map3-===>"+map3);

          if(ctParent==0)
          {
           groups.add(ctName);
          }

           if(ctParent!=0)
           {
             int ctP= movie.getInt("ctParent");
             System.out.println("ctp-->"+ctP);
             for(int j=0;j<demo.length();j++)
             {


             if(ctP==ctCategoryId)
             {
                 System.out.println("matched--"+ctP+"=="+ctCategoryId);
                childs.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
                childs.get(i).add(new ArrayList<String>());
                 childs.get(i).get(j).add(ctName);

             }

           }
           }
```

I want to place the childrens to that corresponding parent. In above code it will returned only parents. Childs will not be displayed and also it wont be under respective parents.

I want to compare category ID with parent and place all the data with respect to each other.Finally it returns to Expandable List class.

So anyone help me out. How to perform this operation.  ???????????

Comment: You won't be able to have three levels without writing your own list code. The stock Android expandable lists only do a group and a child list.